# Are there differences between the Wii U and PS3 versions of Lego Marvel Superheroes?

Tags: ps3, wii-u

I'm trying to decide what system to buy Lego Marvel Superheroes for, Wii U or PS3.

Are there differences between the two versions, such as Wii U Gamepad functionality, platform-exclusive characters or significantly better/worse graphics on either system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying the Wii U version. I play on the GamePad, and if anyone joins me they use a regular Wii remote + nunchuck.

Switching characters and using the map is a *lot* easier using the gamepad. I zoom around the map and pick from the gigantic list of characters simply by tapping and dragging on the gamepad, without ever opening a menu on screen. The other player has to struggle with tiny menus (because of the split screen) and an intrusive map.

I think another difference between the Wii U version and the PS3 version is the lack of DLC for the Wii U, but I can't really find a lot of information about that. It could be that the DLC characters are already available to unlock on the Wii U using a code.

So, I'd say that character selection and map on the gamepad is the main difference between the Wii U version and other versions (except maybe for the 3DS).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The Wii U has better resolution graphics and features off screen play, as well as co-op (one on TV, one on game pad)

This is the best version of the game for me, hands down!

Comment: A Wii with better graphics than a PS3! The world's gone mad!

Comment: My guess is that the PS3 version also has co-op (the previous lego games did, too). If the graphics quality (and off-screen play) is better on Wii U, and the PS3 version doesn't offer anything extra, I'll go with the Wii U version. Thanks!